# How to transform a flat object to a nested object?

Tags: typescript, decorator, class-transformer

I have 3 classes as follows:

```
class Server {
    @Expose({ name: 'APP_PORT' })
    @Type(() => Number)
    port: number

    @Expose({ name: 'APP_TAG' })
    @Type(() => String)
    tag: string
}

class Database {
    @Expose({ name: 'DATABASE_PORT' })
    @Type(() => Number)
    port: number

    @Expose({ name: 'DATABASE_NAME' })
    @Type(() => String)
    name: string
}

class Global {
    @Type(() => Server)
    server: Server

    @Type(() => Database)
    database: Database
}
```

I will convert the `plainObject` below into `instance` with the following code:

```
import { plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer'

const plainObject = {
    APP_PORT: 5000,
    APP_TAG: '1.0.1',
    DATABASE_PORT: 8000,
    DATABASE_NAME: 'test',
}

const instance = plainToInstance(Global, plainObject)
console.log(instance)
```

The returned result is as follows:

```bash
Global {
  server: undefined,   
  database: undefined, 
  APP_PORT: 5000,      
  APP_TAG: '1.0.1',    
  DATABASE_PORT: 8000, 
  DATABASE_NAME: 'test',
}
```

It is not what I expected. I want it to be like this:

```
Global {
  server: {
    APP_PORT: 5000,
    APP_TAG: '1.0.1',
  },
  database: {
    DATABASE_PORT: 8000,
    DATABASE_NAME: 'test',
  },
}
```

What adjustments do I need to make to `the 3 classes above` to achieve what I want ?

Additional information is that I temporarily solved it by changing the `plainObject` to the following:

```
const plainObject = {
    server: {
        APP_PORT: 5000,
        APP_TAG: '1.0.1',
    },
    database: {
        DATABASE_PORT: 8000,
        DATABASE_NAME: 'test',
    },
}
```

But it is not a "pure" decorator approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could try @Transform operator to transform the properties to object. For e.g. below

```
@Transform(p => ( property1: p.nestedObj.property1, property2: p.nestedObj.property2 }));
  nested: any;
```